# Finding the exchange rates of a currency using the exchange rates of another currency

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Knowing that 1 EUR is equal to:

| Currency | Rate |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1.1807 |
| JPY | 129.64 |
| BGN | 1.9558 |
| CZK | 25.413 |
| DKK | 7.4371 |
| GBP | 0.8484 |

Is it possible to find what are the exchange rates of 1 USD to those currencies?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can three or more currency exchange rates simply be multiplied?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/88966/can-three-or-more-currency-exchange-rates-simply-be-multiplied)

Comment: @KBDave It does answer that it is possible, but I couldn't find a way to achieve this in that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible.

Since $1$ EUR = $1.1807$ USD, it means that $1$ USD = $0.8470$ EUR.

Therefore, it is simply a matter of multiplying the rate of each currency by $0.8470$.

For example, to find the exchange rate of $1$ USD to JPY, we simply multiply $129.64$ by $0.8470$, giving us $109.80$. It might be helpful to think of the calculation this way: $1$ USD = $0.8470$ EUR = $109.80$ JPY.

Using this method, it is possible to find the exchange rates of $1$ USD for the mentioned currencies.

I hope that helps!